# Django save override not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to override django's default model save method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.pk:
        ct = Cart()
        ct.save()
        dct = Dummycart()
        dct.save()
        self.cart=ct
        self.dummycart = dct
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
     super(User,self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

but this is creating new object every time i update thid model,it's strange behaviour

Comment: I don't know if this will fix it, but you should call super like this -> `super(User,self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Gocht interesting  it worked !! Thank You

Comment: Good for you, I am posting it as an answer to help someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) like this:

```
super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```